# Terraform: create data source only when var is set?

Tags: terraform

I am writing a module to set up some servers on Hetzner and I want to enable the user to either

- provide an already deployed ssh key using it's fingerprint as a variable
- or add a new ssh-key by providing it's path as a variable if no fingerprint has been provided

my variables.tf looks like this:

```
variable "ssh_key" {
  # create new key from local file
  default = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}

variable "ssh_key_existing_fingerprint" {
  # if there's already a key on Hetzner, use it via it's fingerprint
  type = string
  default = null
}
```

my main.tf:

```
# Obtain ssh key data 
data "hcloud_ssh_key" "existing" {
  fingerprint = var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint
}

resource "hcloud_ssh_key" "default" {
  name       = "servers default ssh key"
  public_key = file("${var.ssh_key}")
}

resource "hcloud_server" "server" {
  name          = "${var.server_name}"
  server_type   = "${var.server_flavor}"
  image         = "${var.server_image}"
  location      = "${var.server_location}"


  ssh_keys      = [var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint ? data.hcloud_ssh_key.existing.id : hcloud_ssh_key.default.id]
```

The idea was to only obtain the data source ssh key if the fingerprint is not empty and then add either the key from the data source or the local key as fallback.

However, it doesn't work like this:
The data source fails because an empty identifier is not allowed:

```
data.hcloud_ssh_key.existing: Reading...
╷
│ Error: please specify a id, a name, a fingerprint or a selector to lookup the sshkey
│ 
│   with data.hcloud_ssh_key.existing,
│   on main.tf line 11, in data "hcloud_ssh_key" "existing":
│   11: data "hcloud_ssh_key" "existing" {
```

How would one accomplish such a behavior?

Comment: "it doesn't work like this." - its not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: multiple errors actually, I think it's in the way I approach the goal:
1. Can't define a data source with an empty identifier
2. the conditional in the resource doesn't work either

Comment: What errors? Can you provide them?

Comment: @Marcin: added the error message to the post; the second issue I was able to solve

Comment: What is the actual value of `var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint` that you are using?

Comment: well it's either a fingerprint of an ssh key or the default which is null

Comment: I mean, **exactly** when you run the code and get the error, what is the var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint? Null or not?

Comment: in this case it's null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in this case it's null

It can't be null. Null by default eliminates the `fingerprint` attribute. Thus you are literally executing `hcloud_ssh_key` without any attributes, explaining why you get your error:

```
# this is what you are effectively calling
data "hcloud_ssh_key" "existing" {
}
```

Either ensure that you have always non-null value, or provide `id`, `name` as alternatives when `fingerprint` is null.

**update**

Make it optional:

```
data "hcloud_ssh_key" "existing" {
  count = var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint == null ? 0 : 1
  fingerprint = var.ssh_key_existing_fingerprint
}
```

Comment: that's *exactly* the point of my question - how can I dynamically create the data source if the fingerprint is there or not if it isn't.
I know I can't retrieve the key without any identifier. But how do I solve this?

Comment: @MichaelNiemand You can use count as in the updated answer.

Comment: Oh! So the data source then selects the ssh key number 0 which is equal to no ssh key?

Comment: @MichaelNiemand Yes. you have to use index 0 later on. Obviously you have to use the same condition everywhere else where the data source would be used.